# Using Crystal Reports, we want to suppress a section based on user input in a parameter

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, suppress

The parameter has yet to be setup, but it will be to determine what jobs to pull (Open, Soft Closed, Closed, or All). So, if the user says they want Open jobs to print, we want the section to suppress if ContractStatus<>Open.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Section Expert, highlight the section you want to suppress. Next to Suppress click on the formula button (x-2). Do not check the Suppress box! Create a formula like:

```
{tableName.ContractStatus} <> {?ParameterName}
```

This will suppress the section if the field name value does not equal the parameter value.

Comment: It says that the parameter has to be a number, but we just need it to be a string O for Open, S for Soft Closed, etc.

Comment: When you create the parameter, you can define what type it is. Right-click on the paramter, click Edit. Change type from Number to String. Is your field ContractStatus a string field?

Comment: No, ContractStatus is a number field, but it needs to be a string. In other words, 1=Open, and so forth. Would I just have a formula that does that conversion and then that's what the parameter looks at?

Comment: Correct. You can use cStr({tableName.ContractStatus}) <> {?ParameterName}.

Comment: For record selection purposes, the parameter needs to be a number, but for the formula it says it needs to be a string?

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have misunderstood. If ContractStatus is a number, then create your parameter as a number. Add the possible values to the  parameter (0, 1 , 2) and in the Description field you enter the appropriate value (Open, Closed, etc.). That way you won't have to convert types back and forth and the user still knows what 0, 1, 2 means. Then you can use the original formula.