# Suppress page footer if parameter value is empty in Crystal Reports

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, suppress

I went through an SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915828/using-crystal-reports-we-want-to-suppress-a-section-based-on-user-input-in-a-pa), and tried implementing it in my Crystal Report. The issue I am facing is that I am trying to use it on an Optional Number Parameter ({?EnteredAmount}) field that can be left blank in order to generate the report.

I want to suppress my Page Footer if no value is entered and so as suggested I am clicking on the Formula field for Suppress(No Drill-Down) after selecting 'Section Expert'.

This is the formula I am using -

```
PageNumber <> TotalPageCount OR isNull({?EnteredAmount})
```

When I try to generate my report without entering a value, I am shown with a 'Parameter has no value' error. 
All I want to do is hide the page footer when there is no value entered in that parameter - is this the right approach? Or is there an alternative for the same?

Comment: Maybe you should workaround. Try to pass 0 or -1 or null instead of not set the parameter. Or try to create another parameter (boolean) to indicate if there is an EnteredAmount.

Comment: Yes I did exactly this - put up a Boolean parameter in order to hide/show the footer. Thanks for the suggestion.